Find all values $c\in\mathbb{R}$ for which the improper integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^c}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}dx$ converges.
Find all values $c\in\mathbb{R}$ for which the improper integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^c}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}dx$$ converges.
If $c\le\frac{1}{2}$, then the integrand $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing. Then look at $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n),$$ which diverges when $n=0$. Then by the integral test $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^c}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}dx$$ diverges for $c\le\frac{1}{2}$.
I believe this diverges for $c>1$, but I'm not sure how to show this. I don't know how to consider the case $\frac{1}{2}<c\le1$.

Hint: On $(1,\infty)$ use the fact that $x^{2}+x <2x^{2}$ and $\int_1^{\infty} x^{c-1}dx$ diverges for any $c\ge 0$.

Consider also the antiderivative which is an incomplete beta function.

$\displaystyle c \in \left(-1/2, 0\right)$

Split the integral into two: from $0$ to $1$ and from $1$ to $\infty$. We have
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{x^c}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{x^{c-1}}{\sqrt{1+\frac 1x}}dx\ge \int_1^\infty\frac{x^{c-1}}{\sqrt{2}}dx.$$
This diverges if $c\ge0$. Also we have
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^c}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}dx= \int_0^1\frac{x^c}{\sqrt x\sqrt{x+1}}dx= \int_0^1\frac{x^{c-\frac12}}{\sqrt{2}}dx.$$
This diverges if $c\le-\frac12.$
On the other hand, when $-\frac12\lt c\lt 0$, we have
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^c}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}dx\le 
\int_0^1\frac{x^c}{\sqrt{x}}dx = \int_0^1 x^{c-\frac12} dx \quad\text {converges,}$$
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{x^c}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}dx\le 
\int_0^1\frac{x^c}{\sqrt{x^2}}dx = \int_0^1 x^{c-1} dx \quad\text {converges.}$$

Split the integral into a sum of $\int_0^1$ and $\int_1^{\infty}$. By definition, the original improper integral is convergent if and if both of these integrals converge. The second integral is $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{-c}\sqrt{x^2+x}}$. The dominating power of $x$ here is $-c+1$, and so by limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{x^{-c+1}}$ we get that it converges if and only if $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{-c+1}}<\infty$, which happens if and only if $-c+1>1$, if and only if $c<0$.
Similarly, in the first integral $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^{-c}\sqrt{x^2+x}}$ the dominant power is $-c+\frac{1}{2}$, so this time make a limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{x^{-c+\frac{1}{2}}}$. We have convergence if and only if $-c+\frac{1}{2}<1$, if and only if $c>-\frac{1}{2}$.
So together we get that the integral converges if and only if $-\frac{1}{2}<c<0$. Of course we used the fact that the integrand is non negative, which is why comparison tests are allowed here.
